# Longest alphabetical Order sub String from a String in Scala

Tags: scala

Need to write the below logic in Scala code
I have a string let say 'abcsfdhdefghihqwtpqr'
need to print the longest string from the above that is in alphabetical order
like from above string the sub strings in alphabetical order is 
abc,defghi,pqr and the logest is defghi so the result will be defghi 
So how to write this above logic in scala ?

below is the code I have written

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val setofletters: String = "aaakkcccccczz"
    /* 15 */

    val output: Int = runLongestIndex(setofletters)
    println("Longest run that first appeared in index:" + output)
  }

  def runLongestIndex(setofletters: String): Int = {
    var ctr: Int = 1
    var output: Int = 0
    var j: Int = 0
    for (i <- 0 until setofletters.length - 1) {
      j = i
      while (i < setofletters.length - 1 &&
             setofletters.charAt(i) == setofletters.charAt(i + 1)) {
        { i += 1; i - 1 }
        { ctr += 1; ctr - 1 }
      }
      if (ctr > output) {
        output = j
      }
      ctr = 1
    }
    output
  }
}
```

but getting error += is not a member of int

Can help me to change the code and to resolve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code uses many mutable variables and doesn't look very Scala-like at all.

Here's a different approach.

```
val str = "abcsfdhdefghihqwtpqr"

List.unfold(str) { s =>
  if (s.lengthIs > 1) {
    val pairs = s.sliding(2)
    val (a, b) = s.splitAt(pairs.indexWhere(p => p(0) > p(1))+1)
    if (a.isEmpty) Option(b, "")
    else           Option(a, b)
  }
  else if (s.nonEmpty) Option(s, "")
  else None
}.maxBy(_.length)  //res0: String = defghi
```

Note: `unfold()` is newly available with Scala 2.13.

---

I don't have 2.11 installed, but this should work.

```
val str = "abcsfdhdefghihqwtpqr"

assert(str.nonEmpty)
(str.head+str).sliding(2).foldRight(""::Nil){
  case (p, hd::tl) =>
    if (p(0) > p(1)) "" :: p(1) + hd :: tl
    else                   p(1) + hd :: tl
  case _ => Nil  //just to suppress the warning
}.maxBy(_.length)  //res1: String = defghi
```

---

**Explanation**

- `sliding(2)` - Pair up each letter with its neighbor: `"ab"`,`"bc"`,`"cs"`, etc.
- `foldRight` - Process each pair from right to left (end to start).
- `""::Nil` - The accumulator will be a `List[String]` starting with a single element of an empty string. (Could also have been written as `List("")`.)
- `case (p, hd::tl)` - Put the current pair of letters to be processed into the variable `p`. Split the accumulator into its head and tail parts.
- `p(1) + hd :: tl` - The 2nd letter of the pair is always added (pre-pended) to the current head of the accumulator. If the two letters are not in alphabetical order then a new, empty, head element is also added to the accumulator.
- `str.head+str` - Because only the 2nd letter of each pair is being added to the accumulator, we have to make an adjustment so that the 1st letter of the original string is also included.
- `maxBy(_.length)` - Pretty easy to understand. Comment this out to see the result of the `foldRight` operation.

Comment: I am having scala version 2.11 can you help me to simply code for the same ? https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh

Comment: Thanks for your help it works, can you explain me how its work ? https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh

Comment: whats the use of assert ? https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh

Comment: That's just a quick-and-dirty way of saying "this won't work on an empty `String` so don't try". There's a better solution using `.headOption` and `.getOrElse()` but I didn't want to add to the solution's complexity.